# How to make inline style use state in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want the display of my elements to be none. So i use inline style in the React element to make display: none. Then after setTimeout runs, the display goes to an empty string, so that my content shows. But my display is always an empty string. The state is not being passed to the inline style, so the value none is never assigned. How can I pass state to inline styles?

I tried `` style={{display:`${this.state.hidden}`}} ``
and `style={{display: this.state.hidden}}`

```
class Home extends Component{
    state={
        hidden: 'none'
      }

      showHello=()=>{
          this.setState({
              hidden: ''
          })
      }

        showName=()=>{
        this.setState({
            hidden: ''
        })
    }

    showFullStack=()=>{
        this.setState({
            hidden: ''
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      setTimeout(()=>this.showHello(), 2500);
      setTimeout(() => this.showName(), 20000);
      setTimeout(() =>  this.showFullStack(), 10000);
    }

    render(){
      return(
    <div className='home-div'>
        <h2 className='hello-header'  style={{display:`${this.state.hidden}`}}>Hello, I'm</h2>
        <h2 className='name-header'  style={{display:`${this.state.hidden}`}}>Sean</h2>
        <h2 className='full-stack-header' style={{display: this.state.hidden}}>I'm a Full Stack Web Developer.</h2>
        <a className='resume'>Download my resume here!</a>
        <a className='github'>View my GitHub here!</a>
        <h1 className='arrow'>&#x21E9;</h1>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated, I am somewhat new to React, so if this is a novice mistake, forgive me.

Thank you!

Comment: The code seems to run just fine, What is the issue?

Comment: It won't work for me, all of the elements I want to hide, are shown before my setTimeout runs, I want them to be shown AFTER setTimeout runs

Comment: well.. after 2.5 seconds, you tell it to say hello. say hello removes the display none property from them all because they all read the same value. Are you wanting to conditionally show individual ones after their timer?

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense, I think I see where you're going with this. Yes I do want them to conditionally show after their timer. So I need to make 3 different pieces of state that means I assume?

Comment: See my answer for a more dynamic way to do it. You can use individual pieces of state, or an array with the names in the array like I wrote up. :)

Comment: @Skyline also your code works, as you said with creating 2 other variables: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/mZdeNX?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Skyline your welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to conditionally show items, i would use an array and check the value. 

[**See it live!**](https://jsfiddle.net/wbxe5hgv/)

```
const displayMap = {
  false: 'none',
  true: 'block'
}

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    display: []
  }

  showMessage = (name) => {
    this.setState({
        display: [...this.state.display, name]
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=> this.showMessage('hello'), 2500);
    setTimeout(() => this.showMessage('name'), 20000);
    setTimeout(() =>  this.showMessage('full-stack'), 10000);
  }

  render(){
    const { display } = this.state
    return(
      <div className='home-div'>
        <h2 className='hello-header' style={{display: displayMap[display.indexOf('hello') >= 0]}}>Hello, I'm</h2>
        <h2 className='name-header' style={{display: displayMap[display.indexOf('name') >= 0]}}>Sean</h2>
        <h2 className='full-stack-header' style={{display: displayMap[display.indexOf('full-stack') >= 0]}}>I'm a Full Stack Web Developer.</h2>
        <a className='resume'>Download my resume here!</a>
        <a className='github'>View my GitHub here!</a>
        <h1 className='arrow'>&#x21E9;</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I do have an unrelated question haha, if you're up for answering it! On that same page, while the elements are hidden, my other component my about component, is pushed up into my Home component, but as the elements display, they push the about component down. I'm using padding to solve this, so my home component appears as if doesn't get smaller, but the padding is excessive, is there another option? I can open a new SO question and post the code if you want.

Comment: If you can replicate the issue in a Fiddle or something where i can see the issue in the browser I can help. padding/spacing issues are pretty hard to fix without that though

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Your code will work.

```
    render(){
const { hidden } = this.state;
          return(
        <div className='home-div'>
            <h2 className='hello-header'  style={{ display:  hidden }}>Hello, I'm</h2>
            <h2 className='name-header'  style={{ display:  hidden }}>Sean</h2>
            <h2 className='full-stack-header' style={{ display:  hidden }}>I'm a Full Stack Web Developer.</h2>
            <a className='resume'>Download my resume here!</a>
            <a className='github'>View my GitHub here!</a>
            <h1 className='arrow'>&#x21E9;</h1>
        </div>

    )}
    }
```

Comment: This has no change in functionality from the original code :/

Comment: It has. Have a look.  https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-lake-udmof?fontsize=14

Comment: No its not that was his question. If you see skyline code it is not hiding tags initially.You code works fine but unnecessary complex.

Comment: no, what the op wants is each individual item (hello, name, fullstack) to be hidden and then to show up when the timer finishes. For each individual item / timer